# Website is offline in India

Tags: support

Is this just me or are other users also facing this issue?

This is very frequent. I have been facing this problem for the past two hours.

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: @JonH In the face of screenshotted proof, not entire sure how helpful your comment is.

Comment: @MarkHenderson - He just asked if anyone else is experiencing this, my comment is I'm not.  BTW two other people upvoted the comment...I didn't pay close attention to it being in india because OP never mentioned it.

Comment: @JonH So he did. Apologies.

Comment: @MarkHenderson - No problem it's early friday morning so you smacking me around is very quite fine since I need to wake up anyways.

Comment: yes i too exp it

Comment: How long until someone edits out the "in India" from the title and adds an [india] tag to the question?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Really.  I reference it daily...often multiple times a day.  I'm sure that SO being offline for a day or two would hurt my productivity :).

Comment: @BoltClock seems reasonable; how else are Meta Stack Overflow's experts on India going to find this question that is relevant to their expertise?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately, our CDN (Content Delivery Network) CloudFlare is having issues in India at the moment:

https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/
[image]

Keep an eye on their network status to see if the issue becomes resolved, meanwhile we will look to see if there's anything we can do to alleviate the issue.

---

Just as I posted this, it would appear CloudFlare might have resolved their issues. We will continue to monitor this.

#### 522 Errors reported by CloudFlare:

[image: Errors]

(Times are in US East-Coast time)

Comment: @Zanon Actually I was an elected moderator at Server Fault since 2011, and technically I'm not a moderator anywhere any more since I got hired.

Comment: @Zanon This is my first ever meta post since becoming an employee, so all in all I don't think its too much of a big deal :) I got to keep my diamond on Server Fault because, I don't really know why...

Comment: I thought SE employees had the diamond in all sites. E.g. [Shog9](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Oriol Shog isn't _just_ an employee, he's also on the community team, which has a lot more site interaction than the majority of us.

Comment: Cloudflare issues again (in India) from yesterday (Mar 12). Can you look into this?

Comment: @BhargavRao cloudflare has been having issues in India on and off for over a week now. Unfortunately there is not too much we can do immediately, but we are actively working on solving this issue permanently.