# Stack Overflow experiencing connection issues?

Tags: support, cloudflare

For the last 30 minutes or so, I'm seeing the "Website is offline" message while accessing SO.

Behaviour is random.

Location: India.

Anyone else seeing the same issue?

EDIT:

For clarification, [Cloudfare status](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/) shows no issue though.

[image: Cloudfare status]

Comment: Possibly (and probably) related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315759/website-is-offline-in-india

Comment: @J.Steen But that should have been solved by now and the status shows no issue. Confused. Updated question.

Comment: I'm just working on probability here; it's happened very recently in parts of India so there's a high chance that it'll happen again (something not completely fixed). The fact that it's not on the status page might just be due to delay of reports or caching (ironically) or whathaveyou. You never know. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Right. I was not questioning your opinion though. :)

Comment: cross-site-related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253196/158100

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I just got one of those cloudflare errors too, and I'm in Europe. Only one though, and otherwise no problem.

Comment: @JonasCz still I'm seeing the same issue, on a different ISP...