# Error 522: Connection Timed out Cloudfare

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, cloudflare

Today while browsing Stack Overflow I got this error.

I am in India. The error is not consistent. It stays for a few seconds and then works OK. So far today I have seen this two times.

[image]

I am not sure this question belongs here or not.

Comment: similar/related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315759/website-is-offline-in-india/315760#315760

Comment: Is it consistent? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: i am in India. Error is not consistent. It stays for few seconds and then gone. Today i seen this 2 times.

Comment: Why downvote on this question. At least think before downvoting.

Comment: I suspect that the voters did think.  They thought it was a routing problem and outside the purview of SO.

Comment: @MartinJames How is it outside the purview of SO? They choose the CDN provider not the OP. If the CDN can't connect to SO how is it not the concern of SO?

Comment: CDN provider?  Maybe.

Comment: @MartinJames If anyone did downvote for that reason, they're pretty silly. When there's a problem with SO, you tell SO. I'm not going to go email Cloudflare about someone else's site.

Comment: I think maybe Cloudflare was having problems last week because this happened to me on several different sites.

Comment: Looks like a blip on the Cloudflare side which they seem to have resolved.

Comment: I hope its resolved because i got this error two time on sunday. Till now it is fine.